# Magento 1.9 php extension load installation issue after upgrade php 7

Tags: php, magento, php-7, php-curl

I have upgrade PHP version of my apache 2.4 with php 7. After upgarde I have tried to install magneto 1.9 and got some php extension load issue. Even I have enable extension.PHP extension "curl" must be loaded.

[Link](http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/3009073/353b35cdb8b26918fba74b3b059dee99)

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/105550/how-can-solve-error-magento-1-xx-on-php-7

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have a proper repository source setup on the server. if yes this command should do the job

```
apt-get install php-curl
```

otherwise check installed packages

```
apt-cache search curl | grep -i curl
```

and make sure php7.0-curl is installed